# Examine Worpdress url to check if it has an endpoint

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, endpoint

Is it possible to find out if current Wordpress url is an endpoint page?

- Pretty permalinks are in use
- Can be asked late, after wp_head, but earlier is better

Only using:

```
global $wp_query;
isset( $wp_query->query_vars['articles'] )
```

is **not working** correct. I cant accept that as an answer. No links to that please.

It seems like its more into this issue. The example above `returns true` on archive pages where the slug is `'articles'` or when custom post type using this slug or single page named `'articles'` or another unique slug using `'articles'` *that is not a rewrite rule endpoint "pointing objective"*.

**NOTE:** It also `returns true` if someone has `set_query_var('articles', $articles)` to pass it into a template scope. (Otherwise, the *provided function below* **did work** until I stumbled upon template file plugin(s)).

The problem persists on other examples, as 'locations' or 'address' if variables are set within `set_query_var()`.

Traversing db for all `post_name` only returns post and pages slugs to "remove" from the examine part. The rewrite rules for custom archives are not in the db.

As of AMP pages, the **endpoint could be in the beginning or at the end** of the url, so positioning conditional check is not working either.

The only help so far is this function found somewhere (cutted):

```
function is_endpoint(){

    if(!get_option('permalink_structure')) return false;

    global $wp;
    if(!$wp->request) return false;
    $parts = explode('/', $wp->request);
    if(empty($parts)) return false;

    // https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms
    $reserved = array(
        'revision',
        'nav_menu_item',
        'custom_css',
        'customize_changeset',
        'action',
        'attachment',
        'attachment_id',
        .. AND ALL OTHER FROM CODEX DOCS ...
        'year'
    );

    //global $wp_query (clashes with added stuff);
    global $wp_the_query;
    foreach($parts as $maybe_endpoint){
        if(!$maybe_endpoint || !trim($maybe_endpoint)) continue;
        $maybe_endpoint = trim($maybe_endpoint);
        if(post_type_exists($maybe_endpoint)) continue;
        if(in_array($maybe_endpoint, $reserved)) continue;
        /** if(is_slug($maybe_endpoint)) continue;**/ // MAYBE SOMETHING LIKE THIS?

        /* Final conditional, all other possibilities removed: */
        if(isset($wp_the_query->query_vars[$maybe_endpoint])) {
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it seems it has to **examine rewrite rules** as well to exclude archive/ registered taxonomies slugs.

ANY possible input to this?

Comment: This would really be interesting of could be solved

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function needs to be extended with `get_post_type_archive_link` logic. Without knowing the post type ahead. Examine `if ( $post_type_obj->rewrite['with_front'] ) $struct = $wp_rewrite->front . $struct else $struct = $wp_rewrite->root . $struct;` But please, **someone else** provide a more concrete answer. This is just a hint. Sorry this was ment to be a comment, not an answer. Do not Wote.